# Why can't I make my Tinkers Construct iron parts?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast, minecraft-mods, minecraft-tinkers-construct

I wanted to make an Iron Hammer but when I put the parts in it didn't let me make the hammer head?  Why can't I make my Tinkers Construct iron parts?

Answer (score 6):

You are trying to use a pattern to make the tools. What you need to make is a Smeltery, and then melt down aluminium and copper together to make aluminium brass. Make a normal wooden/stone hammer head and place it on a casting table. Pour out the molten aluminium brass onto the hammer head to create a hammer head cast. You can then pour molten metal (iron, cobalt etc) into the head cast which will make you a metal hammer head. Find out more [here](http://tinkers-construct.wikia.com/wiki/Smeltery)

Comment: You can use gold in replacement of aluminium brass for the cast

Comment: @ModDL True, but I always use aluminium brass because it's cheaper and easier